# Unable to open port 7077

Tags: raspbian, networking, server

I'm unable to connect to a Raspberry PI on same network. Here is my setup :

```
PI1 (server running on this PI)
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ telnet raspberrypi 7077
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to raspberrypi.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

PI2 (connecting to PI1)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ telnet raspberrypi 7077
Trying 192.168.192.55...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I've tried allowing all traffic via iptables. But not sure what else I can try ?

I can connect to service on PI1 from PI2 running on port 8080 :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ telnet raspberrypi 8080
Trying 192.168.192.55...
Connected to raspberrypi.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So issue just appears to be with port 7077 ?

Can see port 7077 is open :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ netstat -pln
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:7077          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2185/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2185/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:6066          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2185/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20016           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 192.168.192.55:123      0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     420      -                   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     762      -                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

Comment: What service are you running on port 7077?

Comment: @jotadepicas apache spark

Comment: It seems that the 8080 is binded to 0.0.0.0, but the 7077 is binded to 127.0.1.1. Perhaps is apache spark on pi2 that's not configured to allow remote connections? (Only accepting connections that come from localhost).

Comment: @jotadepicas should port 7077 be binded to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.1.1 ?

Comment: I think so, because if I'm not wrong that means "any address", and that is a result of how is spark binding the port. Perhaps is related to the parameters you are running spark with? Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398933/how-to-connect-master-and-slaves-in-apache-spark-standalone-mode gives a clue?

Comment: @jotadepicas thanks for link, I don't think this is related to Spark config as I cannot open telnet session on port 7077 from remote machine.

Comment: But if spark is binding the port only to localhost when it opens it at TCP level, I think that you wouldn't be able to telnet or anything else. Could you try running spark specifying your LAN ip address instead? (Not experienced in spark though).